# How to debug an error while bundling Meteor?

Tags: meteor

```
mrt bundle bundle.tgz

Errors prevented bundling:
Exception while bundling application:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My app is working fine in development mode. I've also been bundling and deploying fine for months. 2 days ago I start getting this error. I don't see any javascript errors anywhere. When trying to bundle I get this.

How do I debug?

Edit: I managed to fix this through rolling back in the vcs but would still like some tips on debugging with meteor.

Comment: I found this too. I think it's a bug in UglifyJS, the JS minifier we use. I'm trying to upgrade to a newer version, but this is triggering another bug in Node Fibers. But I'm on it :)